# Sencha Touch Creates unable to destroy pop up while clicking on Container.It creates multiple pop up and creates error for setting data value

Tags: javascript, list, extjs, viewport

While creating Sencha touch application where I am using List View with HTML buttons. While clicking on button I am adding a pop up window on Viewport.But problem is whenever I am clicking on View except area covered by pop panel,pop up gets hide rather than getting destroyed.
and after clicking on html button for other itemlist, it creates 2 pop up view and gets hanged because of same itemId for pop up.

How to destory the multiple pop up panel on viewport.
Sorry,I can't share the code.

Comment: Consider sharing a chunk of code. Can you extract the minimal code snippet required to reproduce this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your window with

```
modal : true,
```

Like this it is not possible to click outside the window. It will always stay on top.

By default, the window is destroyed when it is closed. So either you do not close the window, or you have overridden the closeAction or autoDestroy config.